# Cannot communicate with software serial on particular devices (SIM7600G-H)

Tags: serial, softwareserial

I have 3 devices:

- An [UNO](https://auseparts.com.au/SainSmart-UNO-ATMEGA328P-PU-ATMEGA8U2-Microcontroller) (non-genuine)

[image: UNO]

- An [SMS hat/shield device `SIM7600G-H`](https://core-electronics.com.au/sim7600g-h-m2-4g-hat-for-raspberry-pi-lte-cat4-high-speed-4g3g2g-gnss-global-band-1.html) to communicate with via UART

[image: SMS Device]

- A [USB UART controller](https://core-electronics.com.au/usb-to-ttl-uart-rs232-serial-converter-module-pl2303hx-au-local-shipping.html) for debugging purposes

[image: UART USB]

---

I'm using the UNO to talk to the SMS device via UART at `9600` baud to send and receive SMS commands. I need the hardware port open to debug, and I am trying to use a software port to talk to the SMS device via it's TX RX pins.

But I cannot get the software port to talk to the SMS device at all.

This is the success I've had trying to talk to and from devices. The bold boxes are needed to be solved for this setup to work. ✅ = working coms, ❌ = nothing on coms at all. Read left to right, **HAT serial (SMS DEVICE)** can communicate with UNO hardware serial.

[image: Connection matrix]

And I'm using this code to just relay inputs and outputs between the hardware and software ports for testing.

```cpp
// Must be same on mock and serial
const int baud = 9600;

// Communication with mock hat
SoftwareSerial mockPort(2, 3);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(baud);

  while (!Serial)
  {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  mockPort.begin(baud);
  Serial.println("Mock port has started @ " + String(baud));
}

void loop()
{

  while (mockPort.available() > 0)
  {
    char inByte = mockPort.read();
    // and send to the hardware serial port:
    Serial.write(inByte);
  }

  // while there is data coming in FROM SERIAL, read it and send it back to mock
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char inByte = Serial.read();
    // and send to the mock serial port:
    mockPort.write(inByte);
  }
}
```

Why can't I communicate to the SMS device with the software ports? (or the USB UART as well?) When testing, I can see the UNO's RX light turn on, but I never receive any data back from the SMS device (the serial monitor is just black).

---

Notes:

- I've tried the AltSoftSerial library as well
- I've set the SMS hat's baud rate default to `9600`
- I've tried different communication pins
- I've got the TX pins on RX pins and vice versa

Comment: I am using simcom7600gh but with esp32.
are you sure you are sending the correct AT Commands to the modem?

Comment: @AhmadFirdausIdris All i'm sending is `at`. I've tried with an ESP32 as well. I can't even get the boot message from the hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TX` and `RX` labels mirror the Raspberry Pi. So I swapped the `RX` and `TX` wires to connect as `RX`->`RX` and `TX`->`TX` and now it works